# Using css modules how do I define a global class

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I am using css modules, however a library I use in a component to append tweets with JavaScript adds some elements to my component in the following structure:

```
<div class='user'></div>
<div class='tweet'></div>
```

I want to now style these elements in my css module for the component, as follows:

**MyComponent.css**

```
.user {
 /* styles */
}

.tweet {
 /* styles */
}
```

However of course now my `.user` class changes to `.MyComponent__user___HZWfM` due to the hash naming in the webpack loader.

How can I set a global style in my css module?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the [css modules docs](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), `:global` switches to the global scope for the current selector. e.g. 
`:global(.example-classname)`

So this should work:

```
:global(.tweet) {
    text-align: left;
}
:global(.user) {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Or define a global block

```
:global {
    .tweet {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .user {
        text-align: left;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It's better to probably combine the css if they are intended to be the same with something like
```:global(.tweet), :global(.user) { text-align: left }```

Answer (score 2):

Can use module class with static class with this way.

myStyle.module.css

```css
.moduleClass_g1m59k:global(.StaticClass) {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Output will generate like this

```css
.moduleClass_g1m59k.StaticClass {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Many people have struggled with this and there doesn't seem to be any one agreed upon solution. The one I have settled with involves some tweaking of your bundler and specifically addresses the need to import libraries as-is without having to wrap them or edit them manually.

In my webpack config I have set it to scan all files ending css except those within the 'node_modules' and 'src/static' folders. I import my libraries from here and they dont suffer the classname transforms so I am free to use regular classnames for global css and the className={styles.element} convention as usual for modular css (which will compile down to .component_element__1a2b3 or something similar).

Here is an example of a working production webpack config with this solution:
http://pastebin.com/w56FeDQA