# React.js module.css select hidden element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am using ant design and module css in a react project.
For example, I have a code like below.

```
          <Tabs
            className={Style.PortfolioTabPanel}
            animated={{ inkBar: false, tabPane: true }}
            defaultActiveKey="1"
            centered={true}
            size={"large"}
            tabBarGutter={50}
            tabBarStyle={{
              color: "white",
            }}
          >
            <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
              Content of Tab Pane 1
            </TabPane>
            <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
              Content of Tab Pane 2
            </TabPane>
            <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">
              Content of Tab Pane 3
            </TabPane>
          </Tabs>
```

The problem is exactly here, I can't see .ant-tabs-ink-bar element for example, ant design creates it automatically inside Tabs component.

When we wrote normal css, we could do this like this:

```
   <Tabs
    className="PortfolioTabPanel"
    animated={{ inkBar: false, tabPane: true }}
    defaultActiveKey="1"
    centered={true}
    size={"large"}
    tabBarGutter={50}
    tabBarStyle={{
      color: "white",
    }}
  >
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
      Content of Tab Pane 1
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
      Content of Tab Pane 2
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </TabPane>
  </Tabs>
```

But now, when I type

```
.PortfolioTabPanel .ant-tabs-ink-bar { 
   background-color: red !important; 
}
```

in module.css file, the browser cannot see the selector because module.css has changed PortfolioTabPanel class name to PortfolioTabPanel_dynamical_id.

Has anyone encountered such a problem and found a solution?

Comment: Try to use `tabBarStyle` for `backgroundColor`

Comment: Firstly sorry for my bad English. isn't there any other way to do this? sometimes there are elements that ant-design does not give style props. what should we do then?

Comment: You can change the `Global state`, You can also load `ant.design css` before main css and use `!import`

Comment: I dont understand. Can you explain it? what is the Global state?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, use `Global Style`. https://v2-pro.ant.design/docs/style

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite global styles using module.css file, you can do it as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#exceptions)

```
:global(.PortfolioTabPanel) .ant-tabs-ink-bar { 
   background-color: red !important; 
}
```

related question [Using css modules how do I define a global class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34279517/14207720)